# Microsoft AvroRecord doesn't contain the value deserialized through Avro

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro, kafka-consumer-api

I have a java code for a Kafka Producer which sends a GenericRecord as a value to the kafka broker. I have to consume this message through a c# client (Kafka consumer). I have registered the schema of java class through SchemaRegistry and receiving the schema at the C# client properly. But when I use Microsoft Avro Deserializer to parse my bytes array, the AvroRecord created doesn't contain a method to display my message. Following is the code for Java Kafka Producer :

```
    public class OrderProducerAvro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServerCoordinates);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");
        props.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://10.250.33.228:8081");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);

        int numberOfMessages = 10;
        Random rand = new Random();
        try (KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props)) {

            while (numberOfMessages-- > 0) {
                //Order order = new Order(numberOfMessages, rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(2000), LocalDateTime.now().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli());
               Order order = new Order();
                order.setOrderName("XYZ");
                Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(order.getClass());
                GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);


                schema.getFields().forEach(r -> avroRecord.put(r.name(), order.getOrderName() + rand.nextInt(2000)));

                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("POCtopic1", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), avroRecord));
                System.out.println("Sending msg: " + avroRecord);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Producer dies here!!!");
    }
}
```

Following is the code for Order class :

```
public class Order {
    public String getOrderName() {
        return orderName;
    }

    public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
        this.orderName = orderName;
    }

    String orderName;

}
```

The c# client code for AvroDeserializer is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Confluent.Kafka.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.Schema;
using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.Container;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class AvroDes : IDeserializer<AvroRecord>
    {
        String schema;
        public AvroDes(String s)
        {
            this.schema = s;
        }


        public AvroRecord Deserialize(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
          //  Console.Write(schema);


            var serializer = AvroSerializer.CreateGeneric(schema);
            var memStream = new MemoryStream();

            memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            memStream.Position = 0;

           // var rootSchema = serializer.ReaderSchema as RecordSchema;

            AvroRecord actual = (AvroRecord)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);




            return actual;
        }


    }
}
```

The schema of the Order class is :

```
{"type":"record","name":"Order","namespace":"amit.poc.order","fields":[{"name":"orderName","type":"string"}]}
```

I want to get the name as sent by the Java Kafka Producer (i.e. "XYZ") by doing something like this :-

```
actual.orderName
```

Kindly help me with this or just suggest me some other way of developing a kafka consumer in c#

Note:- I am using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro dll for c# client

Comment: Solved. The first 5 bytes were actually used for getting schema id. So the position of memstream must start from 5.